# Ошибка при удалении динамического char*

Tags: c++, visual-studio, char

При удалении динамического `char*` выскакивает ошибка.
Возникает в MS Visual Studio 2015, проверял на cpp.sh вроде все норм.

```
// ConsoleApplication4.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
using namespace std;

int time_to_int(char* Time) {
int h;
int m;
if (strlen(Time) != 5 && strlen(Time) != 4) {
    cout << "Wrong time";

    return -1;
}
else if (strlen(Time) == 5) {
    char* temph = new char[3];
    char* tempm = new char[3];
    strncpy(temph, Time, 2);
    temph[3] = '\0';
    h = atoi(temph);
    strncpy(tempm, &Time[4], 2);
    tempm[3] = '\0';
    m = atoi(tempm);
    delete[] temph;
    delete[] tempm;
}
else {
    char* temph = new char[3];
    char* tempm = new char[3];
    strncpy(temph, Time, 1);
    temph[2] = '\0';
    h = atoi(temph);
    strncpy(tempm, &Time[3], 2);
    tempm[3] = '\0';
    m = atoi(tempm);
    delete[] temph;
    delete[] tempm;
}
if (h > 24 || h < 0 || m>60 || m < 0) {
    cout << "wrong time";

    return -1;
}
else {
    cout << h << " " << m << "\n";
    return h * 60 + m;;
}
}
int main()
{
char* t = "3:22";
int tt = 0;
tt = time_to_int(t);
cout << tt<<"\n"; 
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

[image: вот собственно скрин ошибки]

Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Индексы в массиве из трех элементов могут быть от 0 до 2.

Вы пишете за границы распределенной памяти:

```
char* tempm = new char[3];
...
tempm[3] = '\0';
```

и др.

То есть вот этим `temph[3] = '\0';` скорее всего затираете место, где начинается `tempm`.

Comment: а при strncpy(temph, Time, 2); обязательно выполнять temph[3] = '\0'; ?

Comment: Если я не присвою конец строки, при выводе получу строку и еще какой то мусор в ней?

Comment: Спасибо разобрался)